# I set IDENTITY_INSERT to ON but I get a SqlException saying it's OFF

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql, identity, identity-insert

I'm trying to grab thousands of invoices (and other stuff) from a text file and insert them into SQL Server 2008.  I wrote a little console app to do this and it uses LINQ to SQL.  After I insert all the existing invoices I want the `Invoice_ID` to be an identity column and auto-increment, so I have it designed as such:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Invoice]
(
 [Invoice_ID] int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    /* Other fields elided */
)
```

Before I start inserting invoices I call a stored procedure that contains the following line:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Invoice] ON;
/* Other lines for setup elided */
```

After I've submitted my changes I call another stored procedure with the following line:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Invoice] OFF;
/* Other lines for clean up elided */
```

When I try inserting my invoices and submitting the changes I get the following exception:

> SQLException: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Invoice' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

I ran SQL Profiler and I can see that it is indeed setting `IDENTITY_INSERT` to `ON` before trying to perform the inserts.  I do not see it being set to `OFF` anywhere.  I'm pretty new to the SQL Profiler, so maybe there's an event I can enable that will provide me with more info to try and debug this.  Any ideas?

I've tried tweaking values in the .dbml file that's used by LINQ to SQL.  I have the `Invoice` table's `Auto Generated Value` set to "False", `Auto-Sync` set to "Never", and the `Server Data Type` set to "Int NOT NULL".  Normally I'd have them set to "True", "On Insert", and "Int NOT NULL IDENTITY", respectively, but when I do I can see that SQL Server is excecuting:

> SELECT CONVERT(Int,SCOPE_IDENTITY()) AS [value]

rather than inserting the `Invoice_ID` that I provide.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190356.aspx

If you look down, you can see:

> If a SET statement is run in a stored
>   procedure or trigger, the value of the
>   SET option is restored after control
>   is returned from the stored procedure
>   or trigger. Also, if a SET statement
>   is specified in a dynamic SQL string
>   that is run by using either
>   sp_executesql or EXECUTE, the value of
>   the SET option is restored after
>   control is returned from the batch
>   specified in the dynamic SQL string.

Comment: Well darn.  Could have sworn I used to have it working, but clearly I'm mistaken.  Thanks for the help!  :)

Answer (score 2):

While the scope of the IDENTITY_INSERT seems to be a problem, the solution I've found and tested in EF v4.1 is to open the connection first so that the session remains open.  E.g.

```
using (SiteDataContext context = SiteDataContext.Create())
{
    context.Connection.Open();
    context.ExecuteStoreCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT [EnumValue] ON");

    var val = new EnumValue()
    {
        ID = 2000000,
        Value = "just a test",
    };
    context.AddToEnumValues(val);
    context.SaveChanges();

    context.ExecuteStoreCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT [EnumValue] OFF");
}
```

I tested this solution without calling context.Connection.Open(); first, and it failed as described.  Then I added the line it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I would expect SET IDENTITY_INSERT is scoped to the body of the procedure. The most common approach I've seen is to make a stored procedure which uses EXEC to execute dynamic SQL containing both the SET IDENTITY_INSERT and the INSERT itself.